# Gandi SSL certificate, X509 private key values mismatch

Tags: nginx, ssl

I recently regenerated my SSL certificate, which I purchased from Gandi, using the following command:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

This generates 2 files, `server.csr` and `server.key` I then upload the signing request to Gandi, who in exchange gives me my server certificate as well as an intermediate certificate. I then concatenate these.

```
cat my-cert-from-gandi.crt intermediate.crt > chained-certificate.crt
```

Then in my nginx config:

```
 ssl                 on;
 ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificates/chained-certificate.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/server.key;
```

Then when I try to test this config (`nginx -t`) I receive the following output:

```
nginx: [emerg]
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/certificates/server.key")
failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate
routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

The modulus of the `server.key` matches the modulus of `server.csr`. However the modulus of `my-cert-from-gandi.crt` does **not** match the modulus of my private key...

One potential hint here is that the intermediate certificate seems to have changed on Gandi's end since the last time I did this. Previously it contained a single `BEGIN/END` block, and now it contains two. Not sure if this means I have to do something different.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like somewhere in the process either the csr/cert or private key have been swapped for a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have downloaded the wrong signed certificate from your CA, or the CA has committed a bizarre error (and managed to corrupt your key, sign a different key, or something).

Your best course of action is to contact the CA and see if they will help you out, after you double-check you have downloaded the right signed certificate.  They should revoke the one they signed and sign your CSR again.

This cannot have anything to do with the intermediate CA certificates.

Comment: Or they gave the CA the wrong CSR, or they are still using an old private key...  (just filling in some other variations on the same theme)

Comment: The problem was definitely on my end. I must have been pointing my config to an old certificate or I somehow corrupted the certificate in the process. That's what I get for debugging while sleep deprived.